# Pop3 Over SSL/TLS in Common Lisp

Tags: ssl, common-lisp, pop3, sbcl

Can anyone point me to a Common Lisp library (specifically for SBCL on Linux) for pulling pop3 email over SSL/TLS?  [Cl-pop](https://common-lisp.net/project/cl-pop/cl-pop-doc.html) seems fine, but it doesn't seem to support SSL and I'm not sure how to wrap it into [CL+SSL](https://common-lisp.net/project/cl-plus-ssl/) (assuming it's possible).  Does anyone have any suggestions short of rolling your own?

Answer (score 5):

You can redefine the `usocket-connect` function to yield the stream type returned by the SSL library. Then you can define methods to send and receive data over this stream using regular strings (the SSL library only supports binary by default, but CL-POP assumes that strings can be sent). You'll need to depend on the FLEXI-STREAMS library to convert between text and binary. `(ql:quickload :flexi-streams)`

The following is code to make the change and define the needed methods. Since `usocket-connect` is *replaced*, I provide the `:unencrypted` keyword to create a regular socket.

The code could probably be made more efficient.

The `string-to-octets` and `octets-to-string` functions support an `:external-format` argument which allows them to encode/decode many character encoding schemes, including UTF-8, ISO-8859-*, and others. The full list of supported encodings is [documented here](http://weitz.de/flexi-streams/#external-formats). I didn't use `:external-format` in this answer, so it defaults to `:latin-1`.

The code is written against an old version of CL+SSL that seems to have been installed on my system by the Debian package manager. The current versions of `make-ssl-client-stream` and `make-ssl-server-stream` support several more keyword arguments than are supported by the version on my machine. It doesn't matter, however, because CL-POP will use none of these keyword arguments.

```
(defpackage :ssl-pop
  (:use :common-lisp :cl+ssl :usocket :flexi-streams))

(in-package :ssl-pop)    

(let ((old-connect (symbol-function 'socket-connect)))
  (defun socket-connect (host port &key (protocol :stream)
                         external-format certificate key crypto-password
                         (clientp t) close-callback unencrypted
                         (unwrap-streams-p t) crypto-hostname
                         (element-type '(unsigned-byte 8)) timeout deadline
                         (nodelay t nodelay-specified) local-host
                         local-port)
    (let* ((old-connect-args
            `(,host ,port :protocol ,protocol
                    :element-type ,element-type
                    :timeout ,timeout :deadline ,deadline
                    ,@(if nodelay-specified
                          `(:nodelay ,nodelay))
                    :local-host ,local-host
                    :local-port ,local-port))
           (plain-socket (apply old-connect old-connect-args)))
      (if unencrypted
          plain-socket
          (let ((socket-stream (socket-stream plain-socket)))
            (assert (streamp socket-stream))
            (if clientp
                (make-ssl-client-stream socket-stream
                                        :external-format external-format
                                        :certificate certificate
                                        :key key 
                                        :close-callback close-callback)
                (make-ssl-server-stream socket-stream
                                        :external-format external-format
                                        :certificate certificate
                                        :key key)))))))

(defmethod socket-stream ((object cl+ssl::ssl-stream))
  object)

(defmethod socket-receive ((socket cl+ssl::ssl-stream) buffer length
                           &key (element-type '(unsigned-byte 8)))
  (let ((buffer (or buffer (make-array length
                                       :element-type element-type))))
    (loop for ix from 0 below length
         do
         (restart-case
             (setf (aref buffer ix) (read-byte socket))
           (thats-ok () :report "Return the bytes that were successfully read"
                (return-from socket-receive (subseq buffer 0 ix)))))
    buffer))

(defmethod socket-send ((socket cl+ssl::ssl-stream) buffer length
                        &key host port)
  (declare (ignore host port)) ;; They're for UDP
  (loop for byte across buffer
       do (write-byte byte socket)))

(defmethod sb-gray:stream-read-line ((socket cl+ssl::ssl-stream))
  (let ((result (make-array 0 :adjustable t :fill-pointer t
                            :element-type '(unsigned-byte 8))))
    (loop for next-byte = (read-byte socket)
          until (and (>= (length result) 1)
                     (= next-byte 10)
                     (= (aref result (- (length result) 1)) 13))
         do
         (vector-push-extend next-byte result))
    (octets-to-string
     (concatenate 'vector
                  (subseq result 0 (- (length result) 1))))))

(defmethod trivial-gray-streams:stream-write-sequence
    ((stream cl+ssl::ssl-stream) (sequence string) start end
     &key &allow-other-keys)
  (trivial-gray-streams:stream-write-sequence stream
                                              (string-to-octets sequence)
                                              start end))

(defmethod sb-gray:stream-write-char ((stream cl+ssl::ssl-stream)
                                      (char character))
  (let ((string (make-string 1 :initial-element char)))
    (write-sequence (string-to-octets string) stream)))

(defmethod socket-close ((socket cl+ssl::ssl-stream))
  (close socket))
```

Comment: Thanks for giving this a shot. But it's getting protocol-error: 
[code]
A failure in the SSL library occurred on handle #.(SB-SYS:INT-SAP #X0071F720) (return code: 1). SSL error queue:
error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
   [Condition of type CL+SSL::SSL-ERROR-SSL]
Backtrace:
  0: (CL+SSL::SSL-SIGNAL-ERROR #.(SB-SYS:INT-SAP #X0071F720) #<FUNCTION CL+SSL::SSL-CONNECT> 1 -1)
      Locals:
        SB-DEBUG::ARG-0 = #.(SB-SYS:INT-SAP #X0071F720)
        SB-DEBUG::ARG-1 = #<FUNCTION CL+SSL::SSL-CONNECT>
        SB-DEBUG::ARG-2 = 1
        SB-DEBUG::ARG-3 = -1
[/code]

Comment: Also, `sb-gray:stream-read-line` was missing a paren (which looks like it should go after `vector-push-extend`), which is what I added to produce this error.

Comment: That's odd. It worked on my machine. The paren must have been a copy/paste error or something.

Comment: I was able to reproduce that exact error code (140770FC) involving `SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO` by connecting to a non-encrypted POP server. Encrypted POP3 uses port 995 instead of 110.

Comment: Thanks for your continued efforts, but I'm getting the error on port 995, not 110 on both pop.gmail.com and inbound.att.net.

Comment: This produces: `(cl-pop:open-pop-connection :host "pop.gmail.com"
                                     :port 995
                                     :username "notactuallymyemail@gmail.com"
                                     :password "sneaky")`

`A failure in the SSL library occurred on handle #.(SB-SYS:INT-SAP #X0078ABC0) (return code: 1). SSL error queue:
error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
   [Condition of type CL+SSL::SSL-ERROR-SSL]1

Comment: `0: (CL+SSL::SSL-SIGNAL-ERROR #.(SB-SYS:INT-SAP #X0078ABC0) #<FUNCTION CL+SSL::SSL-CONNECT> 1 -1)
  1: (MAKE-SSL-CLIENT-STREAM #<unavailable lambda list>)
      [No Locals]
  
2: (SOCKET-CONNECT "pop.gmail.com" 995 :PROTOCOL :STREAM :EXTERNAL-FORMAT NIL :CERTIFICATE NIL :KEY NIL :CRYPTO-PASSWORD #<unused argument> :CLIENTP T :CLOSE-CALLBACK NIL :UNENCRYPTED NIL :UNWRAP-STREAMS..
  
3: (OPEN-POP-CONNECTION :HOST "pop.gmail.com" :PORT 995 :USERNAME "notactuallymyemail@gmail.com" :PASSWORD "sneaky")`

Comment: Start a fresh SBCL session and it should work. It looks like your sockets are getting double-wrapped, which could happen if you redefined `socket-connect` twice (there's no way to recover the original definition, and each new definition *n* will get its real socket from definition *n* - 1). Also, use the revised version of the code I just edited in. It uses `defmethod` to define `socket-stream` instead of `defun`.

Comment: Thanks again for your persistence! With your updated code, the connection almost worked. I had to define `sb-gray:stream-write-string` for some reason (though the docs say it defaults to `sb-gray:stream-write-char`) which I did and I was able to authenticate on the AT&T servers (Goggle was giving me authentication problems with the client which is another issue I'll deal with). I'm able to successfully run `cl-pop:message-count`, but any of the string related functions keep getting an end-of-file error, so it looks like we may need to tweak `sb-gray:stream-read-line`.

Comment: For completeness, here's how I defined `sb-gray:stream-write-string`.
`(defmethod sb-gray:stream-write-string ((stream cl+ssl::ssl-stream)
                                        (str string) &optional start end)
  (loop for i across str do (sb-gray:stream-write-char stream i)))`

Comment: Here's the error I'm getting when trying to read messages: `end of file on #<CL+SSL::SSL-STREAM for #<FD-STREAM for "socket 192.168.1.75:47537, peer: 98.138.13.170:995" {1007159B13}>>
   [Condition of type END-OF-FILE]`

Comment: `0: (READ-BYTE #<CL+SSL::SSL-STREAM for #<FD-STREAM for "socket 192.168.1.75:47537, peer: 98.138.13.170:995" {1007159B13}>> T NIL)
  1: ((:METHOD SB-GRAY:STREAM-READ-LINE (CL+SSL::SSL-STREAM)) #<CL+SSL::SSL-STREAM for #<FD-STREAM for "socket 192.168.1.75:47537, peer: 98.138.13.170:995" {1007159B13}>>) [fast-method]
  2: (READ-LINE #<CL+SSL::SSL-STREAM for #<FD-STREAM for "socket 192.168.1.75:47537, peer: 98.138.13.170:995" {1007159B13}>> T NIL #<unused argument>)
  3: ((:METHOD CL-POP::READ-MULTI-LINE-POP-RESPONSE (T)) #<CL-POP::POP-CONNECTION {1007171C43}> :MASK-DOT? NIL) [fast-method]`

Comment: I'll try to play with it more when I have some free time.  Thanks again though!